# tensorflow-probability error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability' has no attribute 'distributions'

Tags: python, tensorflow, redhat, tensorflow-probability

I was testing tensorflow probability on our grid environment (running on redhat6.10) using the small sample code available at the Tensorflow Probability web page. I was able to import tensorflow_probability, but ran into the following error on executing the next command: 
 features = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.).sample(int(100e3))

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6342260260f2> in <module>
----> 1 features = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.).sample(int(100e3))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability' has no attribute 'distributions'
```

Anybody has an idea? When I ran the same code this time on a window PC, it worked fine.

Comment: Can you 1. share a bit more context around the code you're trying to run, and 2. share the command(s) you used to install, and the output of `pip list`?

Comment: I recently installed TF 2.0 and am encountering this issue. If you compare the docs for 1.13 and 2.0 you'll see that distributions is not referenced in 2.0, nor is it present in the package, hence the error.